# Android: Using html5 to determine geolocation in webview with javascript api

Tags: android, html, geolocation, webview, cordova

I'm currently having an issue with geolocation in a webview. I have a webapp. I'm currently not using phonegap or any other mobile framework. I've been unsuccessful at getting the built-in html5 geolocation javascript api to work on an application that runs in a webview in an android app. The site works fine otherwise from the chrome browser on android 2.0+ (geolocation supported).

I'm compiling against android api version 5.

I've read
 [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267513/using-navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-in-webview-on-android-2-0-phoneg)  already

Phonegap's solution of writing a proxy which wraps the built in call and uses the host activity instead is good, but I'd prefer to use the built in to the webview (webkit) without using phone gap.

I've set the proper permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Here is an example code snippet:

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
pbarDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pbarDialog.setCancelable(false);
pbarDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new MyChromeWebViewClient());
webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
```

...

```
private class MyChromeWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
    // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
    // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
    activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
}

@Override
public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
    // This shows the dialog box.  This can be commented out for dev
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBldr = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    alertBldr.setMessage(message);
    alertBldr.setTitle("Alert");
    alertBldr.show();
    result.confirm();
    return true;
  }

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
    String description, String failingUrl) {
    }
}
```

Has anyone else had issues with getting a web application to work in the webview?

Comment: do you have examples of the html/javascript that you are using.  As it should work.... Just note, that Chrome has only just got geolocation in the dev channel.

Comment: Is there an updated solution to this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Add `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt()` to `MyChromeWebViewClient` as below:

```
private class MyChromeWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
        // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
        activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
        // This shows the dialog box.  This can be commented out for dev
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBldr = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alertBldr.setMessage(message);
        alertBldr.setTitle("Alert");
        alertBldr.show();
        result.confirm();
        return true;
    }

    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}
```

You need to import "`android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions`".

Add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

This will work I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing that 'WebChromeClient' function!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be the same problem with [Android WebView using Geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation). 
I think HTML5 use local database, so you need add some HTML5 requirements like this

```
// HTML5 API flags
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my Working activity class, this is a complete solution which can demonstrate

- Showing loading dialog while the web page is loading
- Ask for permission in marshmallow and above
- Handle webpage error
- check for the internet connection and open setting page
- Handling Geolocation permission with and without dialog

Hope it save someone's time

```
     /**
     * Created by Hitesh.Sahu on 3/24/2017.
     */

    public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;
        private int webViewPreviousState;
        private final int PAGE_STARTED = 0x1;
        private final int PAGE_REDIRECTED = 0x2;
        private CoordinatorLayout rootView;
        private WebView webView;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            rootView = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_view);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                // Marshmallow+ Permission APIs
                fuckMarshMallow();
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE)) {
                    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            webView.setInitialScale(1);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
            // Below required for geolocation
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());

            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

            webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());

            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        }

        /**
         * WebChromeClient subclass handles UI-related calls
         * Note: think chrome as in decoration, not the Chrome browser
         */
        public class GeoWebChromeClient extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient {
            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin,
                                                           final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
                // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);

    //            final boolean remember = false;
    //            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WebViewActivity.this);
    //            builder.setTitle("Locations");
    //            builder.setMessage("Would like to use your Current Location ")
    //                    .setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    //                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    //                    // origin, allow, remember
    //                    callback.invoke(origin, true, remember);
    //                }
    //            }).setNegativeButton("Don't Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    //                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    //                    // origin, allow, remember
    //                    callback.invoke(origin, false, remember);
    //                }
    //            });
    //            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    //            alert.show();
            }
        }

        /**
         * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
         */
        public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            Dialog loadingDialog = new Dialog(WebViewActivity.this);

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                webViewPreviousState = PAGE_STARTED;

                if (loadingDialog == null || !loadingDialog.isShowing())
                    loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, "",
                            "Loading Please Wait", true, true,
                            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                    // do something
                                }
                            });

                loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
            }


            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
                                        WebResourceError error) {


                if (isConnected()) {
                    final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "onReceivedError : " + error.getDescription(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                    snackBar.setAction("Reload", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                        }
                    });
                    snackBar.show();
                } else {
                    final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "No Internet Connection ", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                    snackBar.setAction("Enable Data", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                            snackBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    snackBar.show();
                }

                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view,
                                            WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {

                if (isConnected()) {
                    final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "HttpError : " + errorResponse.getReasonPhrase(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

                    snackBar.setAction("Reload", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                        }
                    });
                    snackBar.show();
                } else {
                    final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "No Internet Connection ", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                    snackBar.setAction("Enable Data", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                            snackBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    snackBar.show();
                }
                super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (webViewPreviousState == PAGE_STARTED) {

                    if (null != loadingDialog) {
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                        loadingDialog = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        /**
         * Check if there is any connectivity
         *
         * @return is Device Connected
         */
        public boolean isConnected() {

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            if (null != cm) {
                NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                return (info != null && info.isConnected());
            }

            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                    Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                    // Initial
                    perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);


                    // Fill with results
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);

                    // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED


                            ) {
                        // All Permissions Granted

                        // Permission Denied
                        Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "All Permission GRANTED !! Thank You :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();

                    } else {
                        // Permission Denied
                        Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "One or More Permissions are DENIED Exiting App :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();

                        finish();
                    }
                }
                break;
                default:
                    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        private void fuckMarshMallow() {
            List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

            final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
                permissionsNeeded.add("Show Location");

            if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
                if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {

                    // Need Rationale
                    String message = "App need access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);

                    for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                        message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);

                    showMessageOKCancel(message,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                                }
                            });
                    return;
                }
                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                return;
            }

            Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "No new Permission Required- Launching App .You are Awesome!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }


        private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(WebViewActivity.this)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {

            if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionsList.add(permission);
                // Check for Rationale Option
                if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For anyone passing `webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());` fixed this issue for us!

Answer (score 0):

You did try this [html5webview](http://www.tandroid.org/html5webview) class.

```
private HTML5WebView mWebView;
String url = "SOMEURL";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
    setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}
```