# Geolocation failed on Android webview and browser

Tags: android, geolocation

I am facing a problem while working on Android Emulator. I am interested in setting the mock location through the LocationManager class and reading the geolocation in the Webview. I cannot read the location in the Webview where the location is read through the HTML5 geolocation API. I have tried on different versions of Android emulator (for API level 8, 12). I looked into previous questions at stackoverflow, but no luck. Let me know if I am missing anything.

I noticed the following issues in my implementation:

1. (In the logcat) WebChromeCliet was notified that the geolocation service failed to start.
2. I tried to set mock location through geo fix telnet command. I did not notice any corresponding information in the logcat messages.

Similar problem I noticed in the Android Browser. The browser also did not detect the location after geo fix command.

FYI, in my code, 
1. The project settings include ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

1. The emulator has the settings for "mock locations" and "GPS support". I also enable 
   geolocation and gps provider.

I will appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use html5 geolocation you have to [use uses-permission android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation#comment30084824_5329707). The html5 geolocation does not work when just coarse location is requested.

Alternatively, it might or might be possible to use [uses-feature android.hardware.location.gps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074228/gps-manifest-gps-in-app-is-optional-want-to-make-it-available-to-gps-less-devi) for an optional use, even though I haven't managed to have the html5 geolocation working with uses-feature (is it a limitation of the Android SDK?).