# Android content rating affected by optional feature

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play, android-productflavors

I am developing an Android application with two flavors (free with ads, and a paid version). It is intended for educational purposes, mostly for children.

The application has a WebView whose content includes a location button (using [html5 geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)), for which ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is needed).

The problem is that when an application can obtain the current location (via uses-permission android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or [uses-feature android.hardware.location.gps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074228/gps-manifest-gps-in-app-is-optional-want-to-make-it-available-to-gps-less-devi)), the content rating "Everyone" gets disabled.

How could I offer a location-free version of the application? I could create separate flavors without the location part (making it 4 flavors in total), but then I would end up with 4 separate applications in Google Play:

- ApplicationName
- ApplicationName free
- ApplicationName (no location)
- ApplicationName free (no location)

Is this the only alternative? For example, having multiple versions of the same app in a single listing, or building the application in some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Multiple APK Support allows creating diferent "dimensions" of the same application under one single listing. However, the content rating will be a single one for all of them (as opposed to different content-ratings per APK).

As per the [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#HowItWorks):

> The concept for using multiple APKs on Google Play is that you have
>   just one entry in Google Play for your application, but different
>   devices might download a different APK. This means that:
>
> You maintain only one set of product details (app description, icons, screenshots, etc.). This also means you cannot charge a > different price for different APKs.

After uploading multiple APKs for the same application, the number of supported devices has increased, but there is only one single "content rating" setting for the whole application, and that depends on the available content ratings of any of the current APKs.