# Android webview location detect javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview, location

I have a web page in which location is getting detected in web browser successfully. And based on location my results are filtered out. I am running same website url in a webview of android app. But in android app that location detection javascript is not working. Any suggestions what to do here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you enabled javascript for the webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable javascript for webview.

To do that,

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
wv.getSettings().setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing the above still didn't work for me, but adding some additional code did - see [Android Webview Geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation)

I added the following to my webview object

```
    // enable geolocationEnabled
    webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);

    // enable JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically, not sure if this is needed
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    // set setWebChromeClient
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    });
```

For some reason `android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback` had to be a fully qualify className, after adding it as an import it was still not recognized by the Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Just one question:  Does the location detection JS work in the Android Browser (not in the Android WebView)?

One thing to try is add the following to your manifest file:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

The second is to setJavaScriptEnabled(true) in your webview.  I just noticed someone answered this below.

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html