# Web app GPS works in Android Native browser but not in app with webview

Tags: android, gps, web-applications

I've made a web app that accesses the GPS on smartphones and tablets.

The app works perfect in the native browser on Android, but when I try to run the app through a webview application that I've made, the GPS doesn't work.

I have set the permissions as described in the documentation:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you missed to activiate something for the WebView.
For example in WebView you have to manually activate JavaScript.

Comment: Javascript is enabled;
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: This fixed the problem: The problem was solved with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

Have you added these permissions in AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Both permissions are added to the Manifest