# How do you get location data through HTML5 embedded in an Android app?

Tags: android, html, webview, geolocation, android-fragments

I'm working on an Android app where, basically, different web pages are embedded in fragments and a list fragment is used to switch between pages. I'm able to get HTML5 location data working through a browser but not when the page is embedded in the app.

Forgetting fragments, I was able to and I can get JavaScript working in the WebView. But even with WebViewClient I can't figure out what to do for getting the geolocation data working. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You have first to Enable Javascript and GeoLocation in your `WebView`

```
WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    // Brower niceties -- pinch / zoom, follow links in place
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
    // Below required for geolocation
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());

}
```

then you can get location data using navigator..

```
function getLocation() {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, handleError);
}
```

Take a look at this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation)