# GeoLocation in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have an Android app that uses a web view. The web view works well, except for the JS that uses getCurrentPosition to locate the user. I have read about this issue and understand that I need to have the right permissions, and that I also have to set `setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`. I have done these things, but am still having a lot of trouble with my Android app. Sometimes the prompt that requests permission to obtain the user's location doesn't even come up. Can anyone help me fix this? I have included the relevant Java file, the permissions from my manifest.xml, and the JS that gets the user's location. Any help would be wonderful!

---

**Here is my Java file:**

```
package com.website.appname;

import android.app.Activity;
//OTHER IMPORTS HERE

class MyClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
            Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}

public class locationPage extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.embed);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.website/page.php");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyClient());
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient { 
            @Override 
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
                view.loadUrl(url); 
                return true; 
            } 
    }
}
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) { 
            webView.goBack(); 
            return true; 
        } 
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
}
```

**Here are the permissions in my manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

**And here is the webpage that is loaded by the web view:**

```
<script>

      if( navigator.geolocation ) {
           // Call getCurrentPosition with success and failure callbacks
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, fail );
      }
      else {
           alert("Sorry, your browser does not support geolocation services.");
      }

      function success(position) {
          // GeoPosition Object
          window.location = "another_page.php?user_lat=" + position.coords.latitude 
          + "&user_lon=" + position.coords.longitude + "&accuracy=" + 
          position.coords.accuracy;
      }
      function fail() {
           // Could not obtain location
      }


 </script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

P.S. I have also tried looking at things like [android webview geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation), which were helpful, but my issue still persists. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like geolocation is timing out before a position i generated. Try setting a timeout period to delay the default timeout period.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,
                                         fail,
                                         {timeout:60000});
```