# Creating a Ractive instance in an Android hybrid app causes a delay and error

Tags: android, webview, geolocation, hybrid, ractivejs

I'm using [Ractive](http://ractivejs.org) in a web app that runs in the WebView component of a hybrid Android app.  The entire web app is local to the device, and installed with the app.

No issues when I run the web app in a desktop browser.

However, in the hybrid app, when I try to create a Ractive instance, there's a delay of about 30 seconds.  And I consistently get this in ADT LogCat:

```
10-31 10:37:58.859: E/SQLiteLog(26299): (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-31 10:37:58.859: E/SQLiteLog(26299): (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
10-31 10:37:58.871: D/WebKit(26299): ERROR: 
10-31 10:37:58.871: D/WebKit(26299): SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db
10-31 10:37:58.871: D/WebKit(26299): Cause - unable to open database file
10-31 10:37:58.879: D/WebKit(26299): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
10-31 10:38:26.984: D/dalvikvm(26299): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 133K, 36% free 8551K/13191K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
10-31 10:38:27.031: D/dalvikvm(26299): GC_CONCURRENT freed 17K, 32% free 9045K/13191K, paused 12ms+5ms, total 44ms
10-31 10:38:27.031: D/dalvikvm(26299): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 28ms
10-31 10:38:27.168: D/dalvikvm(26299): GC_CONCURRENT freed 181K, 29% free 9375K/13191K, paused 16ms+4ms, total 55ms
10-31 10:38:27.168: D/dalvikvm(26299): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
10-31 10:38:27.297: D/dalvikvm(26299): GC_CONCURRENT freed 163K, 27% free 9724K/13191K, paused 15ms+8ms, total 80ms
10-31 10:38:27.297: D/dalvikvm(26299): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 35ms
10-31 10:38:27.410: D/dalvikvm(26299): GC_CONCURRENT freed 187K, 24% free 10126K/13191K, paused 12ms+7ms, total 57ms
10-31 10:38:27.410: D/dalvikvm(26299): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
10-31 10:38:27.562: D/dalvikvm(26299): GC_CONCURRENT freed 277K, 20% free 10571K/13191K, paused 11ms+3ms, total 57ms
10-31 10:38:27.562: D/dalvikvm(26299): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 30ms
```

I get this even when I try to create a stripped down Ractive instance with only `el` and `template` config fields provided.  I don't get the error when I skip creating a Ractive instance.  And none of the code I've written uses geolocation or issues non-local requests.

As you can see, it appears to be trying to do something pertaining to geolocation.  I searched the Ractive source for some hint of that but found nothing (and would have been surprised if I did).

Has anyone encountered this sort of thing before?

Answer (score 1):

Still don't know why instantiating a Ractive instance would trigger the issue.  However, adding this to the activity in which the WebView is embedded solved it:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setGeolocationDatabasePath(this.getFilesDir().getPath());
```

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5423026/369722