# Get gps location using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, gps

I am using tablet, working on html application, want to get gps location without using any network connection.
please suggest me simple ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using JS you can get it like this

```
 <script>
   var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Comment: well you need to set some permissions.. read this. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation"

Comment: Dear, i am directly making a html file and add this javascript portion in that, so where should I add these permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a instance of LocationManager class. and You can use getLastKnownLocation method to find the location. you must pass Location.GPS_PROVIDER as an argument.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location userLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Log.d("Latitude", userLocation.getLatitude());
Log.d("Longitude", userLocation.getLongitude());
```

Comment: Dear, I am working on php, sqlite and yii framework, running application on localhost, but the network connection is not present but the only option is tablets internal gps and i have to get longitude and latitude. so tell me according to my type of programming environment.

Answer (score 0):

**Give the permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**Get the longitude & latitude:**

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

**Save in txt file:**

```
public void generateLatLongOnSDCard(String sFileName, String sBody){
    try
    {
        File rootDirFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "LatLong");
        if (!rootDirFile.exists()) {
            rootDirFile.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(rootDirFile, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

And finally you can read the text file.

Comment: Dear, I am working on php, sqlite and yii framework, running application on localhost, but the network connection is not present but the only option is tablets internal gps and i have to get longitude and latitude. so tell me according to my type of programming environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get more accurate location feed, you should request for updates, the last known location will not be sufficient for you. GPS_PROVIDER will supply only location updates from the gps, not from network provider. However, if you use NETWORK_PROVIDER, you can get more accurate location values indoor.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }
}
```