# How to get user geolocation in ASP .NET core web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a gateway server in asp net core web API c#, I want to get the user's geolocation, I've looked it up and there doesn't seem to be a single doable answer.
please if you know of a way to do this- without having to create my own database of IPs- could you help me.

Comment: Determining a geolocation from an IP address can only be done by using a third party service (or maintaining your own). Suggestion of which one to use are off topic here.

Comment: okay so new question: how do i discover my device's geolocation in asp.net core mvc ?

Comment: I know its a terrible transgression asking a new question in the comment but should I even open a question? because that too I didn't really find and answer to

Comment: Are you talking about requesting a user's location through _JavaScript_ using the browser's Location APIs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461367/get-gps-location-using-javascript