# Selendroid Mobile View: When running script - map is not loaded for my mobile web site, as it requires to enable location access

Tags: java, selenium, mobile, automation, selendroid

I am working on mobile web site which has the following feature:

> 1. A page with map widget with address edit.
> 2. Enter post code/address in the edit and the location is searched and selected

.

I am trying to automate the above scenario.

When I open my mobile web app on firefox/chrome browser on mobile device, I get a popup "do you want to share your location with `www.myweb.com` " - after accepting this popup the map is loaded and i am able to search the locations using address.

I have created a script using selendroid, but the selendroid mobile view app doesn't show any pop-up; map is also not loaded.

It seems the location is not by default shared with the selendroid web view app, Is there is a way we can allow location access for a website on Selendroid web view app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable geolocations on the selendroid driver.
I believe the issue has been covered in full in here: [android webview geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation)