# How to access location in WebView in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, android, webview, maui

My app has permission to access location.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I check if the user already gave permission and if not, I'm calling:

```
await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
```

But opening a webpage in a WebView control that wants to access the device location does not work, I always get:

```
User denied the request for Geolocation
```

What do I need to add / change to be able to read the device location from a WebView control?

Comment: `webpage in a WebView control that wants to access the device location` ?? Please show the code where a webpage would try to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay got it to work. If someone also has a similar issue, here's the solution:

Create a custom WebChromeClient and add it to your WebView control by adding the following code to your WebView Loaded-Event:

```
#if ANDROID    
    ((IWebViewHandler)myWebView.Handler).PlatformView.SetWebChromeClient(new 
    CustomWebChromeClient());
#endif
```

Here's the resource:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?view=net-maui-8.0&pivots=devices-android#handle-permissions-on-android

Comment: What is in the CustomWebChromeClient that is not in WebChromeClient? could you provide the code or why?

Comment: Do you mean the one in this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304287/xamarin-forms-webview-geolocation-issue

Comment: I've added the resource link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open the `Setting` app to enable the permission access for this app.

You can enable the first option or the second option, just as follows:

[image]

Comment: I'm already asking for location permission in code behind. await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>(); But the WebView itself doesn't seem to automatically have permission.

Comment: Could you please post [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can test on our side?