# Geolocation to webview on Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview and I would like to run Android.getLocation () from javascript to give me the user's location using json, I've done this:

MainActivity.java

```
[...]
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/example.html");

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }
[...]
```

WebAppInterface.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class WebAppInterface extends Activity {

    Context context;

    public WebAppInterface(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
[...]
private LocationManager locManager;

    @JavascriptInterface
    public JSONObject getLocation() throws JSONException {
        locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(this.context.LOCATION_SERVICE); #Me da error en esta linea

        Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        JSONObject location = new JSONObject();
        location.put("latitude", loc.getLatitude());
        location.put("longitude", loc.getLongitude());

        return location;
    }
[...]
```

And obviously I've put the permissions

but when executing from javascript I get an error in the first line of getLocation () and I do not know why, apparently it seems to be fine.

Thank you very much

Comment: Check this for more info, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation

Comment: Yet another ...1. ACTIVITY DERIVED CLASS SHOULD HAVE PARAMETERLESS CONSTRUCTOR  2. DO NOT CREATE ACTIVITY BY YOURSELF

Answer (score -1):

Change this line:

```
locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(this.context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

for this one

```
locManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: How this would help? there is no difference if we use [`instnce.FINAL_STATIC` or `Class.FINAL_STATIC`](https://ideone.com/6NMt2e) ... also `this.getSystemService` doesnt make sens as `WebAppInterface` instance is not a valid `Context` ...