# Geolocation API doesn't prompt for location in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation, mobile-browser

Geolocation API asks for user's approval in web browsers and it's easy to handle that but in mobile browsers prompt to enable location doesn't show up until GPS is enabled. For example, prompt for 'www.abc.com needs your location' shows if and only if GPS is on. Is there any way to prompt for location even GPS is disabled and able it via that prompt?

Comment: [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/118189/gps-location-enable-in-xamarin-forms) do you want this in your app?

Comment: No, not in app browser. I need to do this for default android  browser and other browsers like chrome, firefox, opera mini etc.

Comment: [link](https://cnet2.cbsistatic.com/img/asXTCSYDABpmrXdLKt4-C00--XE=/370x0/2017/02/28/095c9593-2d51-47db-9da6-c648d3735464/mapquest-know-your-location.jpg) you mean this?

Comment: Yes, you got me right.

Answer (score 1):

- JavaScript must be enabled in the `WebView`, using 
  WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
- The app needs permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`
- The `WebView` must use a custom WebChromeClient which implements `WebChromeClient.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt()`. This method is called by the `WebView` to obtain permission to disclose the user's location to JavaScript. (In the case of the browser, we show a prompt to the user.) The default implementation does nothing, so permission is never obtained and the location is never passed to JavaScript. A simple implementation which always grants permission is

  webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
      callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
   }
  });

Geolocation uses databases to persist cached positions and permissions between sessions. The location of the database is set using WebSettings.setGeolocationDatabasePath(...). If the location of the database is not set, the persistent storage will not be available, but Geolocation will continue to function correctly otherwise. To set the location of the databases, use

```
webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath( context.getFilesDir().getPath() );
```

for more info

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation)
[link2](https://medium.com/@xabaras/android-webview-handling-geolocation-permission-request-cc482f3de210)