# GPS Icon stays in status bar after closing app that uses GeoClient() in webview

Tags: android, geolocation, android-webview

I'm using code similar to this one:

[Using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in WebView on Android 2.0+ (PhoneGap related)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267513/using-navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-in-webview-on-android-2-0-phoneg)

After closing the app, the GPS icon stays in the status bar and won't go away. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this link solved the situation: [How do I pause Flash content in an Android WebView when my activity isn't visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431351/how-do-i-pause-flash-content-in-an-android-webview-when-my-activity-isnt-visible)

*(the link discusses the problem with Flash plugin, but WebView's LocationListener obviously behaves the same way)*

Basically, when your activity's onPause() is called, you need to call hidden (non-SDK) method onPause() of your WebView instance. Same way for onResume().