# Android Working WebView 2016

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, webview, webkit

I created a website which is not published yet, so I am not gonna share it now. But it's a website build with PHP Framework Nette and Twitter Bootstrap as a Frontend framework.

And I wanted to create simple Android and iOS app. Both apps with webview. It works fine on iOS, however, I cannot make work on Android. I browsed tons of similar issues, but none of them helped me.

So, what do I actually need?

1. Geolocation Access
2. Showing my website in webview

My code:

```
package com.URL.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */


    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);


        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        //view.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U;`Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");



        view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        });

        view.loadUrl("https://www.URL.com");

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.URL.URL/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.URL.URL/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

This did not work when I tried it in android emulators (4.4, 5.1, 6, 7) but it worked when I downloaded it on my old Samsung where is android version 4.4.4.

I don't know if there is not something wrong with my website, because when I tried to load google.com it works fine..But even when I entered just the string "aaa" to my menu and tried to open it in webview, it did not work.

Screenshots of my website in Webview and in browser:

[WebView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH88P.jpg)

[Web Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd5fw.jpg)

I also wanted to add geolocation access popup window.

All of that works on iOS, but I really do not know how to do that on Android. I am primarily Web Developer, so please, forgive me any messy Android code, it's actually for the first time I am working with Android Studio. Thank you for any help!

PS: I wanna open it in the app not as a new browser tab.

Errors:

```
09-16 15:01:01.578 2390-2512/com.URL.URL E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
09-16 15:01:01.972 2390-2512/com.URL.URL E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2167)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:A08E32ECFE7F0000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : BackFramebuffer::Create: <- error from previous GL command
09-16 15:01:06.059 2390-2390/com.URL.URL E/cr_LocationProvider: Caught security exception while registering for location updates from the system. The application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.
```

Warnings:

```
09-16 15:01:00.562 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86_64
09-16 15:01:00.951 2390-2468/com.URL.URL W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
09-16 15:01:01.116 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
09-16 15:01:01.353 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed
09-16 15:01:01.526 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:01.540 2390-2397/com.URL.URL W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.484ms
09-16 15:01:02.184 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:02.770 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2390
09-16 15:01:02.933 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2390
09-16 15:01:03.059 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:03.597 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:03.980 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:04.058 2390-2397/com.URL.URL W/art: Suspending all threads took: 26.284ms
09-16 15:01:05.010 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:05.346 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:05.704 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:06.044 2390-2397/com.URL.URL W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.006ms
09-16 15:01:06.182 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:06.216 2390-2401/com.URL.URL W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.273ms
09-16 15:01:06.485 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:06.729 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:07.035 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:07.277 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-16 15:01:10.719 2390-2390/com.URL.URL W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: can you please add your logs as well, logs will give you idea why it's failing ? Also hope you have all permissions placed in manifest file

Comment: Hello Amod, thank you for your reply, I updated my post with errors, warns and manifest permissions.

Comment: can you try to add < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372931/simple-webview-example-caught-security-exception

Comment: nothing has changed, still the same errors and warns :/

Answer (score 0):

seems related to hardware draw of chromium
emulator is creating with gpu off by default

Try setting "gpu=on" option in emulator
and add "android:hardwareAccelerated="true"  in your manifest

Comment: Hello Tom, thank you for your help. Unfortunately, it's still the same result. Anyway I launched website app "officially" so the website address I am trying to create android app for is called www.nearber.com. If anyone can help me with that, I will be more than happy. Thank you!