# Tracking locations of Android applications with geolocation-API

Tags: android, geolocation

Is it possible to use  http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/ to track location of Android

application without using android.location.Location, android.location.LocationListener,

import android.location.LocationManager classes. I hope by using geolocation API can provide

same API for all mobile platforms to get the GPS. Appreciate if you can provide an example for

geolocation-API.

**How can I get my android mobile location using geolocation-API.?**

Answer (score 0):

There is other [thread on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267513/using-navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-in-webview-on-android-2-0-phone) , which does identify that this API should work just fine, provided that you are defining the permissions in manifest file.

Also as the API is used in web-environment, you would need to then have the code executed in one, for example by using the webview as was with the other question.